# How to resolve Key Error Exception when accessing dictionary key inside an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm currently developing EV calculator using python and django. I get a `key error exception` when trying to access a dictionary key in an if statement inside a function.

To break it down, my calculator function does the following, prompts the user for four input values, `wager_amount, odd1, odd2 and odd_to_bet/back_odd`, based on values user has entered, the function will output `expected value or ev` in jinja html. Something to note is, `odd_to_bet/back_odd` must either be equal to `odd1 or odd2`, if `odd_to_bet/back_odd` is either not equal to `odd1 or odd2`, the function has an `else` block with a message to tell the user to `Please, check the odds again for any typo error!`.

An example:
lets say the user inputs the following values from html form

```
wager_amount = 10
odd1 = 1.54
odd2 = 2.47
odd_to_bet/back_odd = 1.54

This works fine, i'm able to display output without issues
```

the key error exception arises when the user inputs and submits `odd_to_bet/back_odd` a value not either equal to `odd1 or odd2`.

```
wager_amount = 10
odd1 = 1.54
odd2 = 2.47
odd_to_bet/back_odd = 1.52

My expected output should be "Please, check the odds again for any typo error!." displayed in the html.
```

My function code

```
def func_two_way(wager_amount, home_odd, away_odd, back_odd):
    if back_odd == home_odd:
        total_returns = home_odd * wager_amount
        profit = total_returns - wager_amount
        home_prob = 1/home_odd
        away_prob = 1/away_odd
        prob_not_occuring = away_prob
        ev = (home_prob * profit)-(prob_not_occuring * wager_amount)
        
        my_dict = {
            'odd1': home_odd,
            'odd2': away_odd,
            'wager_amount': wager_amount,
            'ev': round(ev, 2),
            'back_odd': back_odd,
        }
        return my_dict

    elif back_odd == away_odd:
        total_returns = away_odd * wager_amount
        profit = total_returns - wager_amount
        home_prob = 1/home_odd
        away_prob = 1/away_odd
        prob_not_occuring = home_prob
        ev = (away_prob * profit)-(prob_not_occuring * wager_amount)
        
        my_dict = {
                    'odd1': home_odd,
                    'odd2': away_odd,
                    'wager_amount': wager_amount,
                    'ev': round(ev, 2),
                    'back_odd': back_odd,
                }
        return my_dict
    else:
        message = 'Please, check the odds again for any typo error!'
        # print(user_res)
        my_dict = {
            'user_res': message,
        }
        return my_dict
```

my view in django

```
def two_way_ev(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        wager_amount = int(request.POST.get('wager_amount'))
        odd1 = float(request.POST.get('odd1'))
        odd2 = float(request.POST.get('odd2'))
        back_odd = float(request.POST.get('back_odd'))

        print(wager_amount)

        my_func = func_two_way(wager_amount, odd1, odd2, back_odd)
        print(my_func)

        context = {
            'wager_amount': my_func['wager_amount'],
            'odd1': my_func['odd1'],
            'odd2': my_func['odd2'],
            'ev': my_func['ev'],
            'back_odd': my_func['back_odd'],
            'user_response': my_func['user_res'],

        }

        return render(request, 'two_way_ev.html', context)

    else:
        return render(request, 'two_way_ev.html', {})
```

html template

```
   <div class="container text-justify">
                   
                  <p>Odd you are backing is {{back_odd}}</p>
                  <p>Your total wager amount is ${{wager_amount}}</p>
                  <p>Expected value is ${{ev}}</p>
                  <p>{{user_response}}</p>
                
                  
                  
                </div>
```

the error message

```
KeyError at /blogapp/two_way_ev/
'wager_amount'
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blogapp/two_way_ev/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: KeyError
Exception Value:    
'wager_amount'
Exception Location: C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\BERNIEBLOG\myblog\blogapp\views.py, line 88, in two_way_ev
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Admin\.virtualenvs\BERNIEBLOG-Vx11UYiR\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.8.0
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Martin13, kindly can you reiterate your statement. I lost you after your code typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick look at your code I can determine that you *Never* initialize the key `'user_res'` in your dictionary *unless* an error occurs, so in some way nothing is going wrong and that is causing your crash.

Your django code tries to build the `context` dictionary and is getting a `KeyError` exception because the `'user_res'` key is simply not there!, a simple solution would be to initialize this key in all your dictionaries, for example like:

```python
my_dict = {
            'odd1': home_odd,
            'odd2': away_odd,
            'wager_amount': wager_amount,
            'ev': round(ev, 2),
            'back_odd': back_odd,
            'user_res' : 'everything went fine!'
        }
```

this would be sufficient in order for your application to work!

P.S, I must also add that it would be a slightly more elegant solution if you had your user simply pick the bet by entering a number (1 or 2 depending on the bet) rather than entering a long floating point value and being frustrated if he has a typo.

Comment: Have edited each dictionary as you are suggested, however am getting the same key error message.

Comment: keep in mind that the same thig applies for any other attributes, meaning that other attributes such as `'wager amount'` must also be carried through in all instances.

As a good practice I would try to first initialize the response dictionary with all the keys having empty values, and then setting the keys in the conditions, this could help with code scalability and maintenability

Comment: you mean i add `wager_amount, odd1, odd2 and back_odd` attributes in the else block dictionary?

Comment: whichever dictionary you are building in all of those blocks is going to have to have all of the keys you are trying to access in the frontend, otherwise you risk incurring into a `KeyError` exception, so you have to ensure that those attributes are **always** present in the dict when the function returns.

Comment: Thank you @Neervana, the hack was to initialize all attributes in each dictionary. The function is printing properly now. Thank you for support

Comment: I'll further point you (and anyone viewing the thread) towards the idea of having a single initialization for the dictionary, in order to abide to the principle of DRY: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself